# using Requests (Python) to send a POST request with FieldStorage

Tags: python, http

Basically what I am doing is submitting a file to my python server and I need the python server then to forward that same file to another API (third party OCR).  I am trying to use the request library, but it doesn't seem to like it.  It tells me, currently, this error:

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'read'

So here is the code that basically runs it.  Any help or points would be greatly appreciated!

Note: self.request.post['file'] is a fieldstorage datatype.

```
import requests

files = {'file': {self.request.POST['fileName'], self.request.POST['file'].file, self.request.POST['type']}}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Edit: Here is the full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 91, in post
    resp = self.save_ocr()
  File "main.py", line 143, in save_ocr
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 421, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 359, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 290, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 427, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 140, in _encode_files
    rf = RequestField(name=k, data=fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You want to pass the actual file object to `requests`, not the wrapper that also contains the filename, etc.: `self.requests.POST['file'].file`.

Comment: @Cameron it still has the same error when I change it to use simply the file.  I am adding the full error to my question now.